# If element have a child with class ".foo" style it like this [SASS]

Tags: html, css, sass

I need to add a specific style for the parent element, but only if this element has a child with the exact name. For example:

```
<div class="parent-element">
   ----! <div class="child-element-1></div> !----
   ----! or !----
   ----! <div class="child-element-2></div> !----
</div>
```

Parent element can have one of this child elements. I searching for something like this:

```
.parent-element {
 parent: &;
 .child-element-1 {
   parent { 
    overflow: scroll;
  }
 }
}
```

it means, if parent has a child 1, style it like this, if child two: style it another way.

Comment: then you can apply two different CSS on its child classes.

Answer (score 0):

Parent selectors by the child are not allowed in CSS. Your best bet is playing around with SASS functions.